# How to get text of div and set in background color of element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background

```
$(".child").css("background-color", $(".child div").val());
```

```
<div class="flexbox" id="flexbox">
    <div class="child">
        <div>#69d2e7</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the value and make it `background-color` of that element but i don't know what's wrong

Comment: Use `.text()` instead `.val()`

Comment: You also need to wrap in $(function() {....});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

You need to use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to getting text of div tag.

```
$(".child").css("background-color", $(".child div").text());
```

If you have multiple `.child` in your document you need to use bottom code

```js
$(".child").each(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", $("div", this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexbox" id="flexbox">
    <div class="child">
        <div>#69d2e7</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div>red</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div>green</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But when i add more than one `.child` elements it doesn't work

Comment: If the code is before the divs, they will not exist to be manipulated, hence you need to wrap them in $(function() {...}); The snippet editor hides that fact

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are referencing the script file correctly and that it is truly in the root of your project. If not use relative paths to specify the location.  Something like:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.3.2js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then it does not appear like you are actually calling the document ready function that prevents jquery from running before the document is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // jQuery methods go here... });
```